# Check in jquery each if some attribute length is equal to something and add some class to ALL elements which attribute will fit to if statement

Tags: jquery, each

I have a form and wanna do validation but not for all in separate, wanna do in each so will not write extra code. Here is my code below

```
jQuery(".editable_addressItem_parent input[type=text]").each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).prev("label").children("abbr").length == 1) {
          jQuery(this).parent().addClass('invalidinput');
          jQuery(this).css({'border':'1px solid #ff0000'});
          valid = false;
          return false;
    }else{
          jQuery(this).css({'border':'1px solid #5ee1a2'});
    }
 });
```

And here is the markup

```
<div class="shipping_address_wholewrap shipping_default_address editable_addressItem_parent">
<div class="shipping_address address_block one_address_item editable_addressItem" id="shipping_address_1">
<p class="form-row form-row form-row-first validate-required formrow_editscreen" id="shipping_first_name_field">
    <label for="shipping_first_name" class="" style="display: inline;">First Name 
        <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text editable_fields" name="shipping_first_name[]" id="shipping_first_name" placeholder="Type here..." value="Test two" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);">
</p>
<p class="form-row form-row form-row-last validate-required formrow_editscreen shipping_last_name_field_editscreen" id="shipping_last_name_field">
<label for="shipping_last_name" class="" style="display: inline;">Last Name 
    <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text editable_fields" name="shipping_last_name[]" id="shipping_last_name" placeholder="Type here..." value="Testing">
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field update_totals_on_change validate-required formrow_editscreen" id="shipping_country_field">
<label for="shipping_country" class="" style="display: inline;">Country / Region 
    <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>
</label>
<select name="shipping_country[]" id="shipping_country" class="country_to_state country_select  shipping_address_select_editscreen editable_fields">
<option value="">Select a country…</option>
<option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
</select>
</p>
</div>
<div class="shipping_default_addresswrap">
    <input type="checkbox" class="default_shipping_address" checked="" value="true"> Default address
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden_default_shipping_address" name="shipping_address_is_default[]" value="true">
</div>
```

With this code it works but only for ONE first input. How i can update the code so it will apply for ALL invalid or empty input fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share markup as well.

Comment: I have no idea what this bit means `[...]bot for all in separate, wanna do in each so will not write extra code`.

Comment: just a typo @Jamiec. See edited

Comment: Updated @MilindAnantwar

Comment: @AnahitDEV: not just one element. markup that shows all inputs that you wanted to target.

Comment: Ok, so "bot" was "but" - but the rest of that sentence is not English!. In addition you're using the selector `.editable_addressItem_parent input[type=text]` yet that class exists nowhere in your markup. This question is unclear in multiple places

Comment: I updated the  markup @Jamiec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opionion, it's the return false exiting the each loop.

Look at this fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/5hewdf4p/1/

** html **

```
<p>test</p>
<ul id="obj">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

** js **

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#obj li').each(function(eq,elem){
        $('body').append('<p>"li" text is '+$(elem).text()+'</p>');
    if($(elem).text() == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

The if expression is immediately validate by the first object, and returning false inside the if statement exits the loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah seems you are right @Nineoclick! But i need that for stopping submitting the form. What else i can do in stead of that return false? Thanks

Comment: Simply, after the each loop, you can count the length of $('.invalidinput') elements and stop submitting the form if that length is > 0. Only, after the loop.

Comment: but am validating the form when submitting.

Comment: I do not understand. If you're validating the form when submitting, you can put your **return false** anyway OUT of the each loop but in the submit controller method. So, when submitting, after the each loop that set classes .invalidinput here and there, put another if, check the $('.invalidinput') length and if that length is > 0 write a "return false".

I do not think so, but if I misunderstood, make a jsFiddle please. Thankyou.

Comment: Seeems yeah you right. Will try with that. Thank you @Nineoclick

Comment: I think your last request does not follow stackOverflow moral rules. When future users will search for an answer to a battle similar to yours, would be in those users opionion to upvote your question (that has a solving answer), if this one would be useful in some way.

Anyway. an advice: always strive to a better approach while writing your questions. Put code, make a jsFiddle if possible, and do your best to follow stackOverflow asking rules. English language is important. Im italian and not the best english writer, but I strive to do so. Hagd.